# Changing table text on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a little JS which changes value on hover and later changes it like it was. My table is built by having 3 columns under each header. What I'm trying to achieve is that if you are hovering one of the columns it will change the text to example `5000` but keeps all the columns sizes same if needed it would have to go through those other columns next to it. As at the moment by reading my code I'm setting it to add the `5000` in the middle columns so columns which are under it will resize because of that.

To make it clear what I'm trying to achieve is: Changing middle column text to `5000` and not resizing other columns because of that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wep-data-P1').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('.wep-data-P1').html('5000');
            $('.wep-data-P1').first().html('');
            $('.wep-data-P1').last().html('');
            $('.wep-data-P1').css('border-right', 'none');
            $('.wep-data-P1').css('border-left', 'none');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.wep-data-P1').html('5000');
            $('.wep-data-P1').first().html('0');
            $('.wep-data-P1').last().html('0');
            $('.wep-data-P1').css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
            $('.wep-data-P1').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
        }
    });
 });
```

```css
.wep-name{
    width: 295px;
}
.wep-data{
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wep-cond{
    text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

th{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

td{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P1</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P2</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P3</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P4</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Apple</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Banana</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Pineapple</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: it's happening because you are removing the border which is 2px, so number of borders removed X 2px is being removed, and the table is being adjusted.

Comment: @inarilo It's happening more likely because of the text. Text is too big and will resize other(s) to be same size

Comment: you're right, the first time it's because of the text, after that it's because of the borders

Comment: if the value changes to 5000 and then stays 5000 the cell sizes will have to change, otherwise this could be achieved with overlays or by using divs instead of tables

Answer (score 2):

You need to set some sizes for you table itself.

I would also suggest for modifying the colors or changes of that nature to use CSS to make it all a bit more logical when you come back to work on it!

This is the CSS I used to make the table fill that area up:

```
    table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-width: 0px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

The borders on tables will cause some slight jumps with the cells - I added border-collapse to make it appear more smooth.

I see you were trying to change the border colors - so I added the CSS for that as well, and then the javascript will instead toggle the "red-cell" class instead of trying to handle all your styles inline like that.

Here's an updated example fiddle using the markup you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/mas51s6j/1/

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add CSS earlier. I have edited first post, now it should make more sense.

Comment: Ah yes - you can change the red to transparent: https://jsfiddle.net/mas51s6j/3/  which will give it the appearance of taking up all three cells and not have the jitter there.

Comment: Thanks, can you try to achieve same thing (using same sizes) with my CSS i have added?

Comment: Well on the mouseleave - if the text remains 5000 it's not possible to have it sit inside of that cell at the width desired and look right since the text will be too large, it will overflow.  But yes - https://jsfiddle.net/w9x8smk0/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting fixed width to `td`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wep-data-P1').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('.wep-data-P1').html('5000');
            $('.wep-data-P1').first().html('');
            $('.wep-data-P1').last().html('');
         
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.wep-data-P1').html('5000');
            $('.wep-data-P1').first().html('0');
            $('.wep-data-P1').last().html('0');
  
        }
    });
 });
```

```css
.wep-name{
    width: 15%;
}
.wep-data{
    width: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wep-cond{
    text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
width:100%;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

th,td{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th class="wep-name">Name</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P1</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P2</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P3</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P4</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">P5</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Apple</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data wep-data-P1">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Banana</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="wep-name">Pineapple</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
            <td class="wep-data">0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is it maybe possible somehow to make the `5000` overlap those two columns next to it? (Those which will be set to empty)

Comment: you want to hide other `0's` & show only 5000 in three coulmns right?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add CSS earlier. I have edited first post, now it should make more sense.

Comment: 5000 overlap those two columns next to it? means exactly what?

Comment: As I added the CSS to first post I think you maybe can understand now what i mean by that.

Comment: Thank You, but now you got the same thing what is happening for me. The middle box where the 5000 will be is resizing boxes/columns below it and that's what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: It's still resizing. I'm using the "Run code snippet" on Stackoverflow

Comment: check full size output

Comment: Thank You, but can't it be done by keeping those boxes as square?

Comment: you can play with width